# Common Lisp - Function which return an element appears n times in a list

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I'm trying to write a function which return an element appears n times in a list.

For example, for a list like : `(setq lst '(a b b b c))`, the function returns :

```
count-list (lst 3) --> b
```

But when there is two element (or more) which appears in n same time, the function only returns the first element :

```
count-list (lst 1) --> a
```

Instead of

```
count-list (lst 1) --> a b
```

Here is the function :

```
(defun count-list (lst nb)
    (loop for x in lst do
        (if (eq (count x lst) nb)
            (return x)
            )
        )
    )
```

What did I miss ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

return tells the count-list function to exit immediately as soon as it finds a hit, so it won't look for other elements matching the count.
One possible solution is this:

```
(defun count-list (lst n) 
  (remove-duplicates 
    (mapcan #'(lambda (x) 
                (when (eql (count x lst) n) 
                  (list x) )) 
         lst )))
```

However, this is very inefficient since for each item the list has to be traversed twice, one for the function itself and one for count, so this would take a time proportional to the square of the length of the list.
A more efficient way would be to accumulate the values (e.g. in an assoc list) and select at the end those items matching the input count number.

```
  (defun count-list (lst n)
    (let* (count-list pair)
      (dolist (x lst)
        (if (setq pair (assoc x count-list))
          (incf (cdr pair))
          (push (cons x 1) count-list) ))
      (mapcan #'(lambda (pair) 
                  (when (eql n (cdr pair))
                     (list (car pair)) )) 
              count-list )))
```

Answer (score 0):

I never used LISP. I assume your problem is that your function returns at the first match. Either create an array in your function for storing all the elements appearing n times and return to that array, or, for example, in Python I would use `print(x)` so the function does not return at the first match, like in your case.